# Fitting ARIMA model with seasonal data with very long period

Tags: r, arima, seasonality

I have the following time series:
[image]

As you can see, there is a seasonal factor (those are daily data with a sampling frequency of 1 minute). Which we can see in this acf plot (4 days worth of data):

[image]

I want to fit an ARIMA model on this data, but should I care of the seasonal component first (the data is stationary)? In R, the arima function does not support a period exceeding 350.

Thank you all!

Comment: Check out Rob J. Hyndman's blog post ["Forecasting with long seasonal periods"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Long seasonal period in a SARIMAX (seasonal ARIMA) model"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/307543/long-seasonal-period-in-a-sarimax-seasonal-arima-model).

Comment: Unfortunately, the above link ["Long seasonal period in a SARIMAX (seasonal ARIMA) model"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/307543/long-seasonal-period-in-a-sarimax-seasonal-arima-model). was removed.